# Vue Js - Radio inputs not updating model value

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an object containing questions data.

I'm looping through these in the view and then aiming to update the objects 'answer' value.

The questions come from an API and are structured as:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "choices": [
            // choices
        ],
        "created_at": "2016-12-08 09:19:30",
        "updated_at": "2016-12-09 15:29:14",
        "answer": []
    },
]
```

They don't come from the API with an answer value but I have added it in the js file.

I then show the question answers in another loop:

```
<div v-for="(choice, index) in question.choices" class="input-row">
    <input type="radio" v-model="question.answer" value="choice.value"/>
</div>
```

I then out the answer into the view:

```
@{{ question.answer }}
```

I can see it's an empty array, but when selecting the radio button the array isn't updated like I thought it would. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Your input have wrong markup to bind the value with a Vue data property.

```
<div v-for="(choice, index) in question.choices" class="input-row">
    <input type="radio" v-model="question.answer" v-bind:value="choice.value"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped. I was also setting up my data and then adding the new properties so they were not reactive. Refactored a bit and now its okay and everything is reactive.